# select second child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to use this to select the second a tag from a list:

```
.container li a:first-child + a { ... }
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there another, ideally pure CSS way (other than `a:nth-child(2)`) or can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: the `+` operator only works for two adjacent elements, there cannot be anything between them

Comment: No, we can't see where you've gone wrong until we get to see your HTML.

Answer (score 31):

Make sure your `<li>` actually has two `<a>` elements as its first two children, and not some other elements around them since those may be invalidating the `:first-child` and adjacent sibling selectors.

If you just want to select the second `<a>` element regardless of what other types of elements there are in your `<li>`, use this selector:

```
.container li a:nth-of-type(2)
```

If your `<li>` will only have exactly 2 `<a>` elements, you can use the general sibling combinator `~` for bonus IE7/IE8 support:

```
.container li a ~ a
```

Or did you mean to find the `<a>` element in the second `<li>` rather than the second `<a>` element in a `<li>` (since "list" probably refers to `<ul>` or `<ol>` here)? If so, you'll want either of these selectors:

```
.container li:first-child + li a
.container li:nth-child(2) a
```

Comment: Or, you know, you could just reverse the styles for subsequent elements using `.container li a ~ a ~ a`.

Comment: @Felipe Alsacreations: I seem to remember you for [tagging this question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3225891/3) with [css-selectors] some time back... I should thank you, as I'm quite in love with CSS selectors, and I think I'm finally going to get a gold badge for what I'd consider a pretty obscure tag tonight. So thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It took me a while to get it. I couldn't imagine somebody has near 1000 upvotes on this tag :)

Answer (score 6):

I suspect your anchors are within list items:

```
<ul class="container">
    <li><a href="">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

In that case, you have to rewrite the style to:

```
.container li:first-child + li a { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `nth-child(2)`:

```
.container li a:nth-child(2){....}
```