# get third col of div class grid in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, grid

I have grid structure like below:

```
<div class="offer-details center-text">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <p>were </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 center-col price-col">
          <p>asdd</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"> 
          <p>
            For questions or to cancel,<br>
            just call <b>12345</b>
          </p>
        </div>
  </div>
```

I need to change text of third div of `.offer-details` using jquery. I tried

```
$(".offer-details .col-lg-3:second-child").html("<p>For inquiries<br>please contact <b>123 456-7896</b></p>");
```

but that is giving error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: second-child`

Is there any way to access/get that div in jquery without giving new class to that div?

Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no pseudo selector named `second-child`. You can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550401/select-second-child)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".offer-details").children().eq(2).html("<p>For inquiries<br>please contact <b>123 456-7896</b></p>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="offer-details center-text">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <p>were </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 center-col price-col">
    <p>asdd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <p>
      For questions or to cancel,<br> just call <b>12345</b>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query selector of `:nth-child(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the n-th child selector for this. Please be aware that the index starts at 1:

> Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived from the 
>     CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting 
>     starts at 1.

https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child:

```
$(".offer-details .col-lg-3:nth-child(2)").html(...l
```