# Select the second child after some element

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the second paragraph after a h1 have a dropcap (the first is author and date).

This works but doesn't do what I want (it makes the first paragraph have a dropcap):

`h1 + p::first-letter {}`

This doesn't work:

`h1 + p + p::first-letter {}`

`h1 + p:nth-child(2)::first-letter {}`

But why not? Can you not combine css selectors like this?

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550401/select-second-child) does not apply and as such is not a dupe.

Comment: *But why not?* --> only your html code can answer this

Comment: I suggest adding the relevant HTML to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the two you say don't work, consider this structure:

```css
h1+p+p::first-letter {
  color: red;
}

h1+p:nth-child(2)::first-letter {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <p>P1</p>
  <p>P2</p>
</body>
```

This gives:

[image]

The first P is blue because we've told it to select the p element which is the second child of its parent - and h1 is the first child (of body as the parent in this example) so the first p element is selected. If you want it to select the child of a certain type then you'd have to use child-of-type rather than nth child.

The second P is red because we've told it to select the immediate sibling of a p element which is itself the immediate sibling of an h1 element.

That is, this setting works to select the second p element.

You state that it does not work which must mean there is something interfering with that selection - another element in between perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

What you might want to do is, if it's possible in your situation, add a relevant class to the `<p>` element. The class could be named `main-content`, for example. Then style it as required: `.main-content::first-letter { ... }`

```css
.main-content::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Stuff in here.</p>
<p class="main-content">Wow look at this!</p>
```

If you really can't add a class, then you can write it like this. This is **not** recommended though:

```css
p:nth-of-type(2)::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Stuff in here.</p>
<p>Wow look at this!</p>
```