# How to apply style for classes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to make it so that the first td with the active class is red, and the second one is yellow

```css
table tr td.active { 
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td class="cell">1</td>
       <td class="cell">2</td>
       <td class="cell">3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="cell active">4</td>
       <td class="cell in-range">5</td>
       <td class="cell in-range">6</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="cell in-range">7</td>
       <td class="cell active">8</td>
       <td class="cell">9</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select second child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550401/select-second-child)

Comment: Basically, you cannot do it with pure CSS, only JS.
Simply because the `td` dont have the same parent, so you cannot apply the `child` selectors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

Comment: Please write a query with proper description & tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only be able to do it with JS:

```js
//Select the Second active
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[1];
//Apply the yellow color on the second element.
element.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

### DEMO

```js
//Select the Second active
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[1];
//Apply the yellow color on the second element.
element.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

```css
td.active { 
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td class="cell">1</td>
       <td class="cell">2</td>
       <td class="cell">3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="cell active">4</td>
       <td class="cell in-range">5</td>
       <td class="cell in-range">6</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="cell in-range">7</td>
       <td class="cell active">8</td>
       <td class="cell">9</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: JS is not mentioned in the question, then how the answer written in JS be accepted?

Comment: @Sinto Because there is no way to answer it without it. And it is not mentioned that JS solution cannot be accepted

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But proper tagging will help to get an answer easier & quickly. And if he does not intend to get an answer in JS, then your time & effort behind this is a waste. Don't you think so? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the second child with `nth-child()`.

```css
td.active { 
  background: red;
}
td.active:nth-child(2) { 
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">1</td>
    <td class="cell">2</td>
    <td class="cell">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell active">4</td>
    <td class="cell in-range">5</td>
    <td class="cell in-range">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell in-range">7</td>
    <td class="cell active">8</td>
    <td class="cell">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not so sure if this is what he wants. Because this will work if the `active` is on the second `td` in any `tr`, not the second `td.active` of the table

Comment: The active classes will changes dynamicly. For example: https://codepen.io/TheTarasik/pen/bGMgBpB for this html you styles does'n work

Comment: @TheTarasik I may have misunderstood something, could you clarify what you want ? From the pen given above, I guess you want the `.active` class to be colored. If it's the first `td` OF THE ITS ROW it should be red, if it's the second of the row, it should be yellow ?

Comment: @Cédric the author wants to have the second `active` in yellow no matter the parent, or its position. So you won't be able to do it so with pure CSS. Because how do you do if the table have more column, less row than the example ?
From the moment, the parents can be different, it is impossible to use the css selector

Answer (score 0):

In pure CSS you may use `:has()` (but it has [limited support](https://caniuse.com/css-has)) and detect every .active element except the first one.

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}

/* make siblings of the first .active element in yellow, if any */
.active ~ .active,

/* every .active element contained in a row that follows another
   row that contains an active element must be in yellow */
tr:has(.active) ~ tr .active {

   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td class="cell">1</td>
       <td class="cell">2</td>
       <td class="cell">3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="cell active">4</td>
       <td class="cell in-range">5</td>
       <td class="cell active in-range">6</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="cell in-range">7</td>
       <td class="cell active">8</td>
       <td class="cell">9</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="cell active">7</td>
       <td class="cell active">8</td>
       <td class="cell">9</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work, there is none with yellow background. Because `active` is not on `tr`

Comment: it doesn't work on firefox. As stated :has is not supported everywhere. try it on chrome or safari

Comment: I am on Opera, it is not either.

Comment: I provided a link about the support.

Comment: okay, it works on chrome, but solution that don't work on most of the browser is not really a solution. And do you do for your example in case there is 2 yellow but he just wants the second one globaly in yellow ?

Comment: sure, but in the next future this will replace a script. So this will be useful sooner or later.

Comment: Sure but it still does not solve the problem of adding the yellow color only for the second yellow, not every second yellow of every row...